# java write to file with paralellism, save order

Tags: java, parallel.foreach

I have a code which produces result in a loop in simmilar fashion:

```
//loop to write header for b (0-5)

(for int a = 0; a <5 ;a++){
   //System.out.print(a + "| ");
   IntStream.range(b = 0, 5 ).parallel().forEach(b -> {
      int result = a*b;
    //System.out.print(result +  " ");
   });
   System.out.println("");
 )
```

This was my attempt. The commented system outs basically done what i needed, except as parallel take's stuff in whatever order, my lines got mixed. How can I make sure, to get something like this? Instead of lines with random order of numbers in?

```
 0 | 0 0 0 0 0
 1 | 0 1 2 3 4
 2 | 0 2 4 6 8
 ....
```

Comment: If you want to use parallelism and save order, why don't just do it the normal way? I mean you are gonna lose every benefit of parallelism if you do that.

Comment: result is actually much complicated calculation in a separate method. The principle what i need is the same as here and I get to the results much faster this way (simply usint intstream instead of second for loop). The only problem here is writing the results in the right order

Comment: You can save the result basing on value of `b`, let's say make a list and do `list.set(b, result)`, but you will have to wait for every result to complete and then print.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your problem is not one that is well-suited for parallelism.  The overhead that parallelism provides far outweighs any savings you get by running your sums at the same time.

That said, you may want to consider using something like `toArray` to collapse your sums to an array, and then print each element in the array.